# ArrayList fields in class constructors

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, constructor, field

I'm currently learning beginner level Java and have a problem with an `ArrayList` when used in a constructor as a parameter.

When I have to initialize an `ArrayList` in the class constructor, I usually write something like this (for the sake of this example, let's assume that I want to create an `ArrayList` of integers as the class field).

```
public class Example {

    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;

    public Example(ArrayList<Integer> myInts){
        this.myList = myInts;
    }
       
}
```

However, when I see people do the same thing in tutorials or textbooks, they write the following code:

```
public class Example {

    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;

    public Example(int myInts){
        this.myList = new ArrayList<>();
        addIntegers(myInts);
    }
 
    public void addIntegers(int myInts){
        this.myList.add(myInts);
    }
      
}
```

Is there a difference between the two examples? I assume mine is the wrong way to do it, but actually running both versions gives me the same results (to my limited understanding, that is), so I'm struggling to grasp what sets these two variants apart.

Comment: In your second example, why do you name a single `int` parameter `myInts` (plural)? An `int` is singular and not a `Collection` type or array. This is confusing an prevents me understanding your problem.

Comment: Have you tried passing a `null` to both examples and then trying to do something with the `ArrayList` field? With the first one it would throw an exception.

Comment: @Glains: typo. Treat it as if it where "myInt".

Comment: I think in the second example the `myInts` arg to the constructor  was also supposed to be an `ArrayList<Integer>`, _not_ an `int`, am I right?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I made a typo: it actually accepts an int called myInt (without the s).

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Thanks for the comment. It does exactly what you said:  it throws an exception in the first case, whereas it prevents me from creating a new object from the class in the second case, because the field is expected to be an int, not null.

Comment: In 1st example, you are having a constructor that initializes the ArrayList with an ArrayList while in 2nd example you are adding integers to the list.

Both ways can be followed just it depends on your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference, yes. In the code presented, one would call the constructor like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
Example example = new Example(values);
```

After object construction, the calling side still has access to `values`, i.e. the internal data structure used by `example`. By manipulating this data structure, the calling side could bring `example` in an unexpected state and cause issues.

To prevent such problems, we normally do not directly use reference-types passed in from the outside for internal states, but generate copies of them. This, in essence, is what the second example does. If we still want to pass a `List` as parameter to the constructor, we can copy the list:

```
public class Example {

    private ArrayList<Integer> myList;

    public Example(Collection<Integer> myInts) {
        this.myList = new ArrayList<>(Objects.requireNonNull(myInts));
    }

    public Example(Integer... myInts) {
        this(Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(myInts)));
    }

    public Example(int... myInts) {
        this(Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(myInts))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }           
}
```

Now if the calling side mutates the `List` passed to the constructor, the internal datastructure within the `Example`-instance is not affected since it operates on a copy of the original list.

Remark: If the list-type is mutable, then copying the list is in general not sufficient; we would have to deep-copy the list (i.e. create a copy of each list-entry). This is - in general - not possible in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer: that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I did it, but I'm not lv 15.

Comment: @CarloBresciani now you are

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks. Sorry, but I'm a new user and this is like my second question I ask.